# android emulator can't start

Tags: android, android-emulator

the dalvik debug monitor log  :

```
09-07 06:44:20.587: E/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
09-07 06:44:22.177: E/BatteryService(75): usbOnlinePath not found
09-07 06:44:22.177: E/BatteryService(75): batteryVoltagePath not found
09-07 06:44:22.177: E/BatteryService(75): batteryTemperaturePath not found
09-07 06:44:22.207: E/SurfaceFlinger(75): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
09-07 06:44:26.847: E/AlarmManagerService(75): unable to query boot class: Invalid argument
09-07 06:44:27.077: E/IPCThreadState(75): IPCThread::waitForResponse checking error 3 : -1
09-07 06:44:27.077: E/JavaBinder(75): BpBinder::transact() returns exception, err is -1
09-07 06:44:27.097: E/System(75): Failure starting core service
09-07 06:44:27.097: E/System(75): java.lang.SecurityException
09-07 06:44:27.097: E/System(75):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
09-07 06:44:27.097: E/System(75):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(SourceFile:177)
09-07 06:44:27.097: E/System(75):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(SourceFile:103)
09-07 06:44:27.097: E/System(75):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:285)
09-07 06:44:27.127: E/EventHub(75): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
09-07 06:44:27.127: E/EventHub(75): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
09-07 06:44:27.797: E/Pv_omxcore(34): RvRegister A return 0
09-07 06:44:27.797: E/Pv_omxcore(34): after RvRegister A return 0
09-07 06:44:27.857: E/(34): Cannot load library: load_library[1135]: Library 'libasfextractor.so' not found
09-07 06:44:27.966: E/OMXCodec(34): OpenCore USES_YUSU_SW=TRUE
09-07 06:44:28.057: E/(34): Cannot load library: load_library[1135]: Library 'libasfextractor.so' not found
09-07 06:44:28.117: E/IBE(75): ------------------loadIbeConfig---0--------
09-07 06:44:28.137: E/NetConnector(75): ---CheckImConnectedThread---2012-09-07   06:44:28
09-07 06:44:28.137: E/OMXCodec(34): OpenCore USES_YUSU_SW=TRUE
09-07 06:44:28.227: E/(34): Cannot load library: load_library[1135]: Library 'libasfextractor.so' not found
09-07 06:44:28.287: E/OMXCodec(34): OpenCore USES_YUSU_SW=TRUE
09-07 06:44:28.307: E/APPCLICK(75): -----AppClickStatistics
09-07 06:44:28.517: E/(34): Cannot load library: load_library[1135]: Library 'libasfextractor.so' not found
09-07 06:44:28.637: E/OMXCodec(34): OpenCore USES_YUSU_SW=TRUE
09-07 06:44:28.737: E/LockPatternKeyguardView(75):  createMotoneLockScreen failed!
09-07 06:44:28.877: E/(34): Cannot load library: load_library[1135]: Library 'libasfextractor.so' not found
09-07 06:44:28.966: E/ThrottleService(75): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
09-07 06:44:28.987: E/OMXCodec(34): OpenCore USES_YUSU_SW=TRUE
09-07 06:44:29.087: E/ZygoteProcess(75): readInt++
09-07 06:44:29.087: E/SystemServer(75): dm binder is null!
09-07 06:44:29.127: E/Zygote(33): writeInt++143
09-07 06:44:29.177: E/ZygoteProcess(75): readInt--: 143
09-07 06:44:29.177: E/Zygote(33): writeInt--143
09-07 06:44:30.537: E/LockPatternKeyguardView(75):  createMotoneLockScreen failed!
09-07 06:44:32.127: E/IPCThreadState(75): IPCThread::waitForResponse checking error 3 : -1
09-07 06:44:38.767: E/DMOpFile(143): Error Parsing DMOperator file: 1 defined, 2 parsed!
09-07 06:44:39.228: E/DMOpFile(143): Error Parsing DMOperator file: 1 defined, 2 parsed!
09-07 06:44:39.926: E/ZygoteProcess(75): readInt++
09-07 06:44:40.107: E/Zygote(33): writeInt++185
09-07 06:44:40.107: E/ZygoteProcess(75): readInt--: 185
09-07 06:44:40.177: E/Zygote(33): writeInt--185
09-07 06:44:42.337: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): apnType is null
09-07 06:44:42.347: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): convertDataState(sender.getDataConnectionState(apnType) is 0
09-07 06:44:42.347: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.isDataConnectivityPossible(apnType) is false
09-07 06:44:42.357: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): reason is gprsDetached
09-07 06:44:42.357: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.getActiveApn() is null
09-07 06:44:42.357: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.getActiveApnTypes() is null
09-07 06:44:42.367: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.getInterfaceName(apnType) is null
09-07 06:44:42.367: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): ((telephony!=null) ? telephony.getNetworkType() : TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN) is 0
09-07 06:44:44.627: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): apnType is null
09-07 06:44:44.627: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): convertDataState(sender.getDataConnectionState(apnType) is 0
09-07 06:44:44.637: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.isDataConnectivityPossible(apnType) is false
09-07 06:44:44.637: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): reason is gprsDetached
09-07 06:44:44.637: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.getActiveApn() is null
09-07 06:44:44.667: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.getActiveApnTypes() is null
09-07 06:44:44.677: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): sender.getInterfaceName(apnType) is null
09-07 06:44:44.677: E/DefaultPhoneNotifier(143): ((telephony!=null) ? telephony.getNetworkType() : TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN) is 0
```

Comment: Does it also fail if you create a new emulator instance?

Answer (score 0):

You restart your IDE and pc then retry.